# Spead operator does'nt work on vuex mutations

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, spread

i cant use spread operators in vuex mutation on nuxt.

**mutation:**

```
EDIT_BALLOON(state, data) {
const index = state.list.findIndex(item => item._id === data._id);
    //state.list[index] = {...data} // not works
    Object.assign(state.list[index], data); **// works**
  },
```

**Action:**

```
async editBalloon( store, form ){ 
    const { data } = await this.$axios.post('balloon-service/balloon/edit', form );
    store.commit('EDIT_BALLOON', data);
  }
```

weirdly importing vuex helpers works like { ...mapState, ...mapMutations }

Any solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Vuex helpers are a different thing. What are you trying to achieve with the destructuring ? Can you give us an example of the input and the wished output ?

Comment: mutation is not working with spread operators, i added functions. thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some data structure ? Here, I don't know what are the inputs you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I understand a bit better the issue here, this is actually a caveat of Vue2 (and essentially JS itself) that you can find more info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

You can actually use `this.$set(state.list, data, index)` rather than `Object.assign(state.list[index], data)` but it actually achieves the same result.

Comment: so it's common issue?

Comment: It's basically how JS works. [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) can help bypassing this caveat, it's actually used in Vue3. But Vue2 and in regular JS, you need to do this yeah.